# How to run a sh file at AWS EC2 reboot/startup

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2

I did this

$  vi  /etc/rc.local

and added 1 line to this file. Now this file looks like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# This script will be executed *after* all the other init scripts.
# You can put your own initialization stuff in here if you don't
# want to do the full Sys V style init stuff.

touch /var/lock/subsys/local
/home/mysh.sh
```

I reboot EC2. But mysh.sh seemed not run.
I confess I am new with Linux.
Thanks

Comment: Did /var/lock/subsys/local get created? And, is /home/mysh.sh marked as executable?

Comment: Yes, there is a /var/lock/subsys/local , which is empty.

I can run mysh.sh like this:


$ sh /home/mysh.sh

Comment: Can your run mysh.sh like: $ /home/mysh.sh - ? Is the last modified time on /var/lock/subsyslocal the same as the boot time?

Comment: the last modified time on /var/lock/subsyslocal the same as the boot time.  Let me try $ sh /home/mysh.sh in file and reboot.

Comment: Thanks. It works now. The script is running under root, not ec2-user as I thought.

Answer (score 2):

Just posting the solution as an answer:

Change ownership of `/home/mysh.sh` to `root`:

```
$ chown root.root /home/mysh.sh
```

Also, make sure it has executable permissions:

```
$ chmod u+x /home/mysh.sh
```